# Phalcon PHP: determine if create or update in model validation method

Tags: php, validation, model, phalcon

I've created a Model in Phalcon.  In it, I have a validation() method.  On create of a record, I want to make sure that a record is getting a name, but I don't want that to be required on update.  How can I determine that with Phalcon?

Comment: What's your validator code? Besides, doesn't the model override all of the values on update, i.e., if the name was not specified are you handling the scenario of ending up with `null` in the `name` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your validations within a function called beforeValidationOnCreate or beforeCreate and it gets hit only on Creation and not updating

```
public function beforeValidationOnCreate()
{
    //Do the validations
}
```

or

```
class MyModel extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function beforeCreate()
    {
        //Do the validations
    }
}
```

Check the link below for more Events that you could use :

[Phalcon PHP Events and Events Manager](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/reference/models.html#events-and-events-manager)

Hope that is close to what you need

Answer (score 2):

It is described better in the Phalcon's [docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#skipping-columns).

```
class Robots extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        //Skips fields/columns on both INSERT/UPDATE operations
        $this->skipAttributes(array('year', 'price'));

        //Skips only when inserting
        $this->skipAttributesOnCreate(array('created_at'));

        //Skips only when updating
        $this->skipAttributesOnUpdate(array('modified_in'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey - I appreciate the answer!  I think the intention for this feature is for allowing the database to set default values (like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, etc) - in order to get around the issue of Phalcon requiring database fields that are defined as NOT NULL.  Thank you for pointing me to this, though.  I upvoted you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have something more complex and want to use the same 'validation' method for both creates and updates you can do this:

```
public function beforeValidationOnCreate()
{
    $this->_isCreate = 1;
}

public function beforeValidationOnUpdate()
{
    $this->_isCreate = 0;
}

public function validation()
{
    if ($this->_isCreate) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```